# rpy2 / R issue in loess function via Python?

Tags: python, r, statistics, pandas, rpy2

I'm trying to call the R function `loess` via Rpy2 in Python on this datafile: http://filebin.ca/azuz9Piv0z8/test.data

It works when I use a subset of the data (the first 1000 points) but when I try to use the entire file, I get an error. My code:

```
import pandas
from rpy2.robjects import r
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
data = pandas.read_table(os.path.expanduser("~/test2.data"), sep="\t").values
small_data = data[0:1000, :]
print "small data loess:"
a, b = robjects.FloatVector(list(small_data[:, 0])), \
       robjects.FloatVector(list(small_data[:, 1]))
df = robjects.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
loess_fit = r.loess("b ~ a", data=df)
print loess_fit

print "large data loess:"
a, b = robjects.FloatVector(list(data[:, 0])), \
       robjects.FloatVector(list(data[:, 1]))
df = robjects.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
loess_fit = r.loess("b ~ a", data=df)
print loess_fit
```

Fitting on `small_data` works but not `data`. I get the error:

```
Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
    loess_fit = r.loess("b ~ a", data=df)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.3.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 86, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2-2.3.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 35, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in simpleLoess(y, x, w, span, degree, parametric, drop.square, normalize,  : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

How can this be fixed? I'm not sure if it's a problem with the R function `loess` or with the Rpy2 interface to it?  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are `-Inf` values in your data:

```
DF <- read.table('http://filebin.ca/azuz9Piv0z8/test.data')
DF[!is.finite(DF[,1]) | !is.finite(DF[,2]),]
#        V1   V2
# 5952 -Inf -Inf
```

Comment: thank you! just noticed it - weird because I did `dropna()` before in `pandas`. is there a way to make `loess` be ok with NA values or should I just pre-remove them

Comment: `Inf` is not the same as `NA`. `loess` deals just fine with the latter (see its `na.action` argument). You could use `DF[!is.finite(DF[,1]) | !is.finite(DF[,2]),] <- NA`.

Comment: `inf` and `-inf` are not considered as missing values in pandas, see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html, so `dropna()` will not have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Why call R, when you can use the [statsmodels package in Python for lowess smoothing](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.smoothers_lowess.lowess.html)?

There's also a Bio.Statistics package for lowess, but it doesn't appear to be as accurate, and I couldn't get it converge for [this lowess example](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/dep/dep144.htm).

Comment: It's worth noting that the OP is using LOESS, not LOWESS.  They are not the same thing.  LOESS came later and is a more flexible generalization.  (You can think of LOESS as a multivariate LOWESS but that is an oversimplification.)  statsmodels has LOWESS, but not LOESS.  (All that being said, the example provided looks to use a univariate model and could be done equivalently with LOWESS.)

Comment: depending on the data size statsmodels function can be incredibly slow. I havent tested it myself but the general opinion seems to be that R implementation is much faster.